# HoloLens Emulator with Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, hololens

Has anyone of you successfully managed to install the HoloLens Emulator with only Visual Studio 2017 present on the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the install instructions:

> If you are using Visual Studio 2017 and do not have Visual Studio 2015
>   installed, you must update the registry to work around a prerequisite
>   check Add or locate this key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\Analog Add a
>   REG_SZ value in that key with name:
>   “OverrideHoloLensSDKPrerequisites”, and value: “TRUE” If you are on an
>   x64 version of Windows, also add or locate this key:
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Analog Add a REG_SZ value in that
>   key with name: “OverrideHoloLensSDKPrerequisites”, and value: “TRUE”

You can use VS 2017 if you never installed VS2015 by doing a registry "fix"

Comment: Can you share screenshot ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [HoloLens Forums](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/6166/visual-studio-2017-rc), it says:

> The Project template for Holographic hasn't been updated for Visual
> Studio 2017 yet. Only Visual Studio 2015 is supported at this time.

So for the meantime, you need to use **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** to use the HoloLens emulator

Comment: Yep, but you can also use the Holographic Simulator in Unity 5.5 too!

Answer (score 0):

On vs2017rc...

Install hololens emulator and vs2015 as required by ms / run holographicapp trought templates / copy thé son ans project files from vs2015/projects to vs2017 project / open it with vs2017 (it will run fine and successfull buil on emulator).

Uninstall vs2015 trought vs2015 installer (All basic features)

Run holographic again in vs2017...And start modify...